# Android Studio, Aplicación no se inicia en dispositivo móvil

Tags: android-studio, apk

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de Android en Android Studio y he decidido instalarla en mi móvil para verla en funcionamiento. Nunca hasta ahora he tenido problemas, he seguido los pasos Build->Generate Apk, me he copiado el archivo .apk en mi dispositivo y lo he instalado desde ahí. La cuestión es que aunque la aplicación se inicia perfectamente en el emulador, en mi móvil no lo hace. Pulso para que se inicie y parece ser que se abre e inmediatamente después se cierra. la versión de Android de mi dispositivo es la siguiente: 6.0.1 y mi archivo Gradle de la aplicación contiene esto:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tigestion.guillermo.calendarioprueba"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.+'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
compile 'com.github.sundeepk:compact-calendar-view:2.0.2.2'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}
```

Nunca me habían dado este tipo de fallos, ¿Alguna idea de porqué puede ser?

Fichero Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tigestion.guillermo.calendarioprueba">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/iconoftalmo"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".PantallaCarga">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
</application>
```

(Editado con explicación)
Vale, ya he encontrado el problema. Las herramientas que he estado usando requieren de una versión de android 26 o superior, y la versión de mi dispositivo es 23. Por eso no se lanza.

Comment: Que error te sale?

Comment: No me da error ni en el móvil ni en el emulador, sencillamente cuando intento abrir la aplicación desde mi móvil parece ser que se inicia e inmediatamente después se cierra. Lamento no poder dar más información

Comment: ¿ Y en Android Studio no tienes la opción de instalar la aplicación directamente, enchufando el dispositivo al pc y via usb?
Yo siempre lo hago así, en Cordova, con Appcelerator. Recuerda que debes activar la depuración USB del dispositivo, y eso no suele fallar, e imagino que en Android se podrá igualmente. Un saludo, espero haber ayudado. [https://androidstudiofaqs.com/tutoriales/conectar-movil-android-studio](https://androidstudiofaqs.com/tutoriales/conectar-movil-android-studio) Revisa ese enlace

Comment: Publica tu manifest y la actividad principal.

Comment: Ya he cambiado la pregunta mostrándolo.

Comment: "Aplicación no se inicia en dispositivo móvil", esto tienen infinidad de causas, deberías revisar el uso del LogCat para Android, para evitar perder horas en lugar de segundos para detectar un problema en la aplicación. Por cierto veo que usas  getSupportActionBar(); cuando tu Activity extiende de AppCompatActivity.

Comment: Y que error debería buscar concretamente para poder ponerme con ello?